# 7z command for unzip -p -a

Tags: zip, 7z

I have a command line execution in my .sh file which unzips the file which is in zip format. Below is the command which unzips the file `unzip -p -a`.

```
elif [ "${FILECOMMANDOUTPUT}" = "Zip" ]
then
 COMMANDTOUSE="/usr/bin/unzip -p -a"
```

But if the file size is larger (say 935 MB) the above command `unzip -p -a` is not working. I've got `7z e -so -bd` command which works if we need to pipe or redirect the output of it somewhere else (to a file) . But I just need a single command which can replace `unzip -p -a` in the above code.

Comment: And why the 7z e *** command is not the right one? If your problem is only the length of this command, I'd suggest creating __alias__

Comment: That was created by me too..I didn't get a solution yet..

Answer (score 0):

If you have java installed try this:

```
    jar xf filename.zip
```

Java supports extracting larger zip files.

Comment: That's not working...am not have Java installed...the data should be visible while its extracting...I am looking for a 7z command which displays the data while extracting..thanks